# VSEPR accuracy against measurements

Tags: physical-chemistry, error-analysis, molecules, software, molecular-dynamics

I started to develop a [VSEPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) application. My question is that what is the accuracy of a VSEPR computation and what variants does it have?

Comment: Better ask on chemistry stack exchange with with improvements like providing details of where you want to apply the Vespr theory

Comment: This is quite a broad question

Comment: How can I transfer the question to chemistry SE?

Comment: Easiest way is to just close it here and ask it there

Comment: Charlie: Could you give me a hint to specialize it? (maybe this covers the second part of my question)

Comment: Actually, if you look at the wiki article on VSEPR, you'll find some examples where VSEPR fails to predict the correct geometry.

Comment: Verktaj: Thanks for the answer. Well, these will be some good motivations for my application. How can I upgrade your answer to the correct answer for my question?